# simultaneous events in console c#

Tags: c#

I've already made the console to beep 4 times with different frequencies and after that to countdown from 5 to 1. But now I wanna make these two events to happen simultaneously - beep and at the same time display a number. I can't find an answer to that on Google and the layman's attempt to write both commands on one line lead to nothing good.
So, is there any possible way to do that or the console doesn't support simultaneous events?

Answer (score 0):

Uh, you need to use [`System.Threading`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx)

```
static void Main()
{
    Thread t = new Thread (beep);
    t.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Your text");
}

static void beep()
{
    //beep function here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do this.

Let's assume that you have two methods: `Beep()` and `PrintNumber(int number)`. Then, you should have a `for` loop to make a sound several times.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    Beep();
    PrintNumber(i);
}
```

This code will make a sound and then print a number. Next, you need to execute these methods in different threads. To create a new thread and run some code in it, you need to use `Tasks`. To create a task, you need to use a factory:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(action);
```

And pass there an action to be performed. So, the complete solution in your case is

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class ConsoleApp
    {
        public static void Beep()
        {
            // make sound
        }

        public static void PrintNumber(int number)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var printTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                        PrintNumber(i);
                });

            var beepTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () =>
                {
                    for (int i = 10; i > 0; --i)
                        Beep();
                });

            printTask.Wait();
            beepTask.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Where `() => {}` is a notation to write a lambda-expressions — small pieces of code without definition of a method.

Comment: Why do you thing it is going to be performed in same times? I can asure u it wont.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski this is how it works on my machine — thread execution start after creating of new task. I can see mixed output in console if I add Console.WriteLine to Beep method. Could you please elaborate why it won't work simultaneously?

Comment: I see, sorry for late responce - so I think I was wrong then if it is tested. Cheers